# Office 365 Exchange Hide from GAL not consitent

Tags: office365, powershell-4.0

we have a hybrid setup with AD user objects syncing from on prem to O365. However, all Exchange mailboxes have been migrated now. Terminated users need to be hidden from the GAL and setting msExchHideFromAddressLists = TRUE in AD and allowing it to sync, seems to work. But for a certain number, it does not and Set-Mailbox -identity yyy -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true errors with `The operation on mailbox "yyy" failed because it's out of the current user's write scope. The action 'Set-Mailbox', 'HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled', can't be performed on the object 'yyy' because the object is being synchronized from your on-premises organization. This action should be performed on the object in your on-premises organization.` So, when I check, it's set in AD but never syncs. I thought perhaps I'd removed their O365 license too soon and this was the cause, but re-licensing and trying to let sync still not working. Any ideas? I have read that this may be a MS bug but could use confirmation. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, do not remove licenses in O365 prior to attempting to hide from GAL. Do so on AD side using `Set-aduser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -Replace @{msExchHideFromAddressLists= $true}` and it will sync over to O365. Thx